# How can i use "beforeinstallprompt" for in-app browser

Tags: javascript, instagram, progressive-web-apps, inappbrowser, beforeinstallprompt

I need to make it possible to install a PWA from the in-app Instagram browser, Android only.
I understand that the in-app browser uses a standard browser
The documentation says that AndroidWebview is supported, but in practice it doesn't work for me.
Lighеhouse - confirms the absence of errors in the PWA
I attach the code

```
let deferredPrompt;

const addBtn = document.querySelector('.add-button');
addBtn.style.display = 'none';

window.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator){

        navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js')
            .then(registration => {
                console.log('Service worker successfully registered', registration);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Service worker registration failed', error);
            });
    }
});

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  deferredPrompt = e;
 
  addBtn.style.display = 'block';

  addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
    addBtn.style.display = 'none';
    // Show the prompt
    deferredPrompt.prompt();
    // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
    deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
      } else {
        console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
      }
      deferredPrompt = null;
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, the Android WebView does not support the `beforeinstallprompt` event unless you do some extra work within the WebView.

Comment: I also would like to know how to use beforeinstallprompt on in-app browser of Android app.

Comment: What does that "extra work" mean?